# Scrollbar disappears from mapView after coming back from detailview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I'm doing an iOS project using ARC and storyboard.

Currently the setup is as followed on the storyboard

```
TabbedBarController
    NavigationController
        MapView = events on map
            UIScrollbar -> To zoom with (yes I want it by bar)
    UIView
    NavigationController
        TableView = List of events
-----
UIView  = Detail
```

So the detailview isn't connected in the storyboard but when on the mapview and you click the disclusre button of the annotation (=event) you go to the detailview  (it's pushed on the navigationstack) but if you click back the scrollbar is gone from the mapview..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the navigationbar that pushed it out of screen.
Normally the navigationbar is hidden, but when I go to a detail page and come back, it shows.

So I added:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:YES];
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];

}
```

And it was fixed!